# Documentation about iOS autocorrect

Tags: iphone, ios, autocorrect

Im writing a paper about spell correction i iOS and i wonder if there's any available documentation from apple about how iOS handles user input in form of validation and generate a possible word that it thinks the user is going to type?

In short terms: I wonder where I can find the documentation behind the auto correct in iOS and how it works.

Thanks.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSSpellChecker_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: Note that `NSSpellChecker` is Mac-only, the iOS equivalent would be `UITextChecker`. Their functionality is quite different.

Comment: Yeah they were quite different. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here is a note](http://appleinsider.com/articles/12/06/28/apple_wants_to_improve_autocorrect_by_detecting_typing_speed_word_intent) about two Apple patents involving autocorrect.

They involve using timing and geometry, parts of speech, and contextual lookup.